# Expectation value of the (single-particle version of the) density operator?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, perturbation-theory, density-operator

I'm trying to understand some statements in a book named Modern Condensed Matter Physics by Steven M. Girvin and Kun Yang in Appendix A Linear-Response Theory. Here, the authors consider the following perturbation

$$H' = \lambda(\mathcal{O} + \mathcal{O}^\dagger)$$,
and gives an example of a single particle subject to a sinusoidal potential
$$H'=2\lambda \cos(qr)=\lambda(e^{-iqr} + e^{iqr})$$
with
$$\mathcal{O} = e^{-iqr} = \rho_q$$.
The authors say that this is the (single-particle version of the) density operator. Now if you want to calculate the static response, you should calculate
$$\chi_i = 2\sum_{i\neq j} \frac{\langle\psi_i\vert \mathcal{O}+\mathcal{O}^\dagger\vert\psi_j\rangle \langle\psi_j\vert \mathcal{O}+\mathcal{O}^\dagger\vert\psi_i\rangle}{E_i - E_j}$$ (from the non-degenerate perturbation theory). But then the authors argue that usually only the cross-terms survive. For the example above, $\vert \psi_i \rangle$ are eigenstates of momentum, and
$$\langle\psi_i\vert \mathcal{O}\vert\psi_j\rangle \langle\psi_j\vert \mathcal{O}\vert\psi_i\rangle = \langle\psi_i\vert \rho_q\vert\psi_j\rangle \langle\psi_j\vert \rho_q\vert\psi_i\rangle =0$$.

(i) My first question is, why $e^{-iqr}$ is the density operator? I have seen something like $a^\dagger a$ is called a density operator, but I'm not sure about this one.

(ii) My second question is, why $\langle\psi_i\vert \mathcal{O}\vert\psi_j\rangle \langle\psi_j\vert \mathcal{O}\vert\psi_i\rangle$ is zero? I think this means that each term is also individually zero (like $\langle\psi_i\vert \mathcal{O}\vert\psi_j\rangle=0$), but then $\chi_i$ will become trivially zero. So after some agony, I thought maybe the authors meant the following
$$\sum_{j\neq i}\langle\psi_i\vert \mathcal{O}\vert\psi_j\rangle \langle\psi_j\vert \mathcal{O}\vert\psi_i\rangle = \sum_{j\neq i}\langle\psi_i\vert \rho_q\vert\psi_j\rangle \langle\psi_j\vert \rho_q\vert\psi_i\rangle =0$$.
I can write this as
$$\langle\psi_i\vert \rho_q \rho_q \vert\psi_i\rangle - \langle\psi_i\vert \rho_q \vert\psi_i\rangle \langle\psi_i\vert\rho_q \vert\psi_i\rangle$$,
but I still cannot show that this should be zero.

Comment: I'm missing a lot of the context, and I'm not familiar with the source you provided. Couldn't it be that the perturbation is *diagonal in the unperturbed* Hamiltonian eigenstate representation? Then you'd have, $\left\langle \psi_{i}\left|\mathcal{O}\right|\psi_{j}\right\rangle =\rho_{q}\left\langle \psi_{i}\left|\psi_{j}\right.\right\rangle $, and $\left\langle \psi_{i}\left|\psi_{j}\right.\right\rangle =0$ for $i\neq j$.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. But if that's the case, $\chi_i$ will be trivially zero (it only has non-diagonal parts). I don't think the authors meant that.